# make two vue methods synchronous

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I currently have two vue methods:

(1) `this.get_saved_searches()`

(2) `this.update_default_select_option()`

How can I make method(2) only run when method(1) is finished?

Comment: Use promises and call method 2 after you've gotten the response from method 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what Derek Pollard mentioned, Have both the methods return promises and use async/await to achieve what you're looking for

Sources: [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise); [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)

```
async bar(){
    await this.get_saved_searches();
    await this.update_default_select_option();
}
```